# Gradient in Convolutional Layer

Tags: conv-neural-network, backpropagation

I have a convolutional neural network that operates on $4$-tensors. I'm trying to calculate the gradient w.r.t. the 4-dimensional filter, i.e. $\frac{\partial E}{\partial f}$, given the gradient w.r.t. the following layer, $\frac{\partial E}{\partial y}$. The dimensional compatibility is as follows:
$$x\,(N, H, W, C_{\text{in}}) \,\ast\, f\,(F_h, F_w, C_{\text{in}}, C_{\text{out}}) \rightarrow y\,(N, \frac{H-F_h}{S},\,\frac{W-F_w}{S}, C_{\text{out}}),$$ where $N$ is the batch size.

I was getting a bit caught up in the tensor notation and summation for $\frac{\partial E}{\partial f}$, so I decided to tackle it by dimensional analysis - I had read that all boils down to another convolution between $x$ and $\frac{\partial E}{\partial y}$.

If you want some concrete values for the dimensions, here they are: $$(64, 28, 28, 1) \ast (3, 3, 1, 2) \rightarrow (64, 26, 26, 2)$$

What I ended up with was this:

$$x^T\,(1, 28, 28, 64)\,\ast\,\frac{\partial E}{\partial y_{2103}}\,(26, 26, 64, 2) \rightarrow f_{2103}\,(1, 3, 3, 2)$$

This does give the right dimensions, but it doesnt seem to generalise to strided convolutions.

Could someone please guide me towards a solution here?